# optimizing CSV export with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

i have recently migrated my export CSV code from core php to code igniter. the code works well but its very slow when exporting very large amount of data..

here is my old code:

```
function exportCSV($qry,$con,$title)
{
$result = mysql_query($qry, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$title."-".date('mdY').".csv");
//echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 if ($row) {
  echocsv(array_keys($row));
 }
 while ($row) {
  echocsv($row);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 }
}

function echocsv($fields)
{
    $separator = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
            $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
        }
        echo $separator . $field;
        $separator = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

and here is my codeigniter code that is very slow... exporting data to CSV with 77000 rows took about 15 minutes excluding the download time..

```
public function exportCSV()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";

    $curr_date_time = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");

    $this->products_model->set_venture($this->selected_venture['abbrev']);

    if($get_data = $this->input->get())
    {
        $data = $this->products_model->export_model($get_data);
        $download = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($data, $delimiter, $newline);
        force_download('export - '.$curr_date_time.'.csv', $download); 
    }
    else
    {
        show_404('page', FALSE);
    }

}

public function export_model($params = NULL)
{
    if ($params != NULL)
    {
        if ($params['name_filter'] != '')
        {
            $this->crawler_db->like('name', $params['name_filter']);
        }

        if ($params['comp_filter'] != '')
        {
            $this->crawler_db->where('fk_competitor_website', $params['comp_filter']);
        }
    }

    return $this->crawler_db->get('pcrawler_'.$this->venture.'.products_final');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code igniter's csv_from_result is really slow for me, i made a different one to suit my needs.. it can be re used for other CSV exports too...

```
public function array_to_csv($array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

usage:

```
$this->array_to_csv($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check database util class can work for you its really simple to generate good CSV files here is the code

```
$this->load->dbutil();

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

please read the document here [Codeigniter CSV export with DB util](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#csv)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at debugging the function, to see where it's actually slow.

Simple way is to use the Benchmarking Class to see if it's the query that's slow, or the call to csv_from_result().

Is it still slow when you don't pass any params to export_model()?  If it's only slow when you run a like or where against the database, then maybe you need to add some indexes?

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/benchmark.html

Once you find the bottleneck, you can go from there to

Comment: the csv_from_result() is the slow one... the query of 77k rows has only 1 second of execution time.

Comment: @ChristianBurgos have you tried stepping through the csv_from_result() function, and see if you can see what's causing the delay?  Are you using the latest version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: yes i am using the latest version of it.. i've used the core php's function and its much much faster...

Comment: I would be interested to know what part of csv_from_result() is being slow, if you can step through and find it

Comment: i am really not sure but i found it to be the culprit. it took about 10-15 minutes exporting from the database to the download excluding the download speed. core php took about just 15-30 seconds from the database to download.. for added note, selecting from the database is about a second or two...

Comment: How many fields are you selecting from your database?  I know you've sorted the issue now, but FYI I ran some tests against a large data set I have, and to pull back 77000 records and pass through csv_from_result(), it takes 108 seconds (1.8 minutes).  The length of the resultant $download string was 8654543 bytes (8.65 MB).